# Strange behaviour of Spring Cacheable returning null after the first call

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis

I encouter a strange problem with one method.. no idea why this one, because it is the same as the other one..

I'm using Redis for the cache, but redis doesn't return me the cached response after the first call..

Springboot parent version : 2.6.3

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/groups", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @Cacheable(value = "groups")
    public GroupsDTO getAllGroups() {
        return iGroupsAndUsersService.getAllGroups();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/users", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @Cacheable(value = "users")
    public UsersDTO getAllUsers() {
        System.out.println("here"); // is displayed the first call
        return iGroupsAndUsersService.getAllUsers();
    }
```

For my first call to /users i get my list of users within 1.5 seconds so OK.
The second call and other one i get null like this (http 200) :

```
{
    "items": null
}
```

I can see that my method as been called only one time, but unlike other methods, the cache is not returning me the cached response..

The endpoint /groups is working without any problem.. these methods do the same job...

```
public interface IGroupsAndUsersService {

        GroupsDTO getAllGroups();

        UsersDTO getAllUsers();
        
}
```

Users

```
@Data
public class Users {
  List<Item> items;

  @Data
  public static class Item {
    public Metadata metadata;
    public String fullName;
  }

  @Data
  public static class Metadata {
    public String name;
  }

}
```

```
public class UsersDTO extends Users implements Serializable{

}
```

Comment: Are both DTOs serializable? Do GroupsDTO have a specific RedisTemplate bean configured? Is there any specific cache configuration for groups or users?

Comment: I edited the question, Both are serializable.
GroupsDTO do not use an extends of Group.
No specific redistemplate bean ( just one for jwt token..)
No specific cache

Comment: not sure about Redis cache, and it's not tightly related, but at spring-context cache we have to @EnableCaching, have a @Bean public CacheManager. Note you can also add in the @Cacheable annotation something like `unless = "#result == null"` so nulls won't be in the cache.

Comment: The @EnableCaching is in the main.
The problem is that there is no null..
The result is displayed on the first call without cache, and then the cache respond with a null object. But it is not at all null.. it is huge..

Comment: `Users` isn't `Serializable` next to that `Item` needs to be `Serializable` to else it won't work unless you specify a specific `RedisSerializer` for these classes yourself.  The default used is the `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer` and it will only serialize stuff that is serializable. Looking at your code `Item` isn't. You might want to try another serializer like the `Jackson2JsonSerializer`.